# How to select section in regular expression in linux commands

Tags: regex, sed, csplit

I have these lines that every line begin a word then equal and several sentence so I like select every section. For example:

```
      delete = \account
          user\
          admin
           admin right is good.
      add = \
          nothing
          no out
          input output is not good 
      edit = permission 
          bob
          admin
          alice killed bob!!!
```

I want to select a section for example:

```
  add = \
      nothing
      no out
      input output is not good
```

I like do it with regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague but you could try the following ...

```
/\s*(\w+) = ([^=]*\n)*/m
```

... subject to the requirement that the last section is terminated with \n.

this works by:

- '\s*' matching some optional leading whitespace
- '(\w+)' capturing the name of the section
- ' = ' matches the space equals space separator
- '([^=]*\n)' it then captures a string that does not include an equals and ends with a newline
- '*' and it does that last bit multiple times

The m flag is then required to set multi-line.

See the following to quickly see the groups that are output for each match ...

https://regex101.com/r/oDKSy9/1

(NOTE: The g flag will probably not be required depending on how you use the regex.)

Comment: Thanks. Can you write this regular expression with sed command?

Comment: For example, replace add section with new value or delete them.

Comment: I find this solution:
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\(add =\([^=]*\n\)*\)/stringReplace/g' fileName

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

I find this solution:

```
csplit -k fileName '/.*=/' '{*}'
```

Thanks @haggisandchips